# from to table for missing values

Tags: r

In the data frame below there are a number of continuous days with missing values. 
I want to create a table that shows the missing days

**Expected output**

Table of missing values

```
from            to 
2012-01-08      2012-01-12
2012-01-18      2012-01-22
2012-01-29      2012-02-01
```

I tried to do it using this code

```
library(dplyr)
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, format = "%d-%b-%Y")
from_to_table_NA <- df %>% 
  dplyr::filter(is.na(value)) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(from = min(Date),
                   to =   max(Date))
> from_to_table_NA
        from         to
1 2012-01-08 2012-02-01
```

As expected, it gave me the minimum maximum dates only for missing values. I will highly appreciate any suggestion on how to get the desired output.

**DATA**

```
df <- read.table(text = c("
Date          value
5-Jan-2012  5
6-Jan-2012  2
7-Jan-2012  3
8-Jan-2012  NA
9-Jan-2012  NA
10-Jan-2012 NA
11-Jan-2012 NA
12-Jan-2012 NA
13-Jan-2012 4
14-Jan-2012 5
15-Jan-2012 5
16-Jan-2012 7
17-Jan-2012 5
18-Jan-2012 NA
19-Jan-2012 NA
20-Jan-2012 NA
21-Jan-2012 NA
22-Jan-2012 NA
23-Jan-2012 12
24-Jan-2012 5
25-Jan-2012 7
26-Jan-2012 8
27-Jan-2012 8
28-Jan-2012 10
29-Jan-2012 NA
30-Jan-2012 NA
31-Jan-2012 NA
1-Feb-2012  NA
2-Feb-2012  12"), header =T)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to group by consecutive days. This can be done by getting the cumulative sum of condition where the differences between days is not exactly 1:

```
df %>% 
  filter(is.na(value)) %>% 
  group_by(g = cumsum(coalesce(Date - lag(Date), 1) != 1)) %>% 
  summarise(from = min(Date),
            to =   max(Date))
```

Gives:

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 x 3
>       g       from         to
>   <int>     <date>     <date>
> 1     0 2012-01-08 2012-01-12
> 2     1 2012-01-18 2012-01-22
> 3     2 2012-01-29 2012-02-01
> ```

Comment: A similar one: `df %>%
    mutate(g = cumsum(!is.na(value))) %>%
    filter(is.na(value)) %>%
    group_by(g) %>%
    summarize(from = first(Date), to = last(Date))`

Comment: @mt1022, ah that's a nice one.

Comment: The main idea is the same. `cumsum` is quite powerful at grouping runs of NAs.